# Any javax.validation Bean annotations to validate the following rules?

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation

I have the bean below in a `java.ws.rs` API class for CRUD:

```
class FooBean {
    BigDecimal ageLowerRange;
    BigDecimal ageUpperRange;
    BigDecimal heightLowerRange;
    BigDecimal heightUpperRange;
}
```

I can’t find the right `javax.validation` annotations can verify the lower/upper fields to be within a range **AND** the following logic:

```
public boolean compre(BigDecimal upperRange, BigDecimal lowerRange) {
    if (upperRange == lowerRange) return true; // handles both param being null
    if (upperRange == null) return false;
    if (lowerRange == null) return true;
    return upperRange.compareTo(lowerRange) > 0;
}
```

Is there a javax validation that does what I want or an alternative way to validate my bean more elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use annotation.

Hibernate validator:

`@Range(min=, max=)`

Or from `javax`:

```
@Min(value=)

@Max(value=)
```

On top of each variables.

Comment: I don't think you can do `@Min(value=ageLowerRange)ageLowerRange`, can you?